# Trouble adjusting Kali linux's settings on virtual box

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I'm new to virtual box and I'm trying to adjust Kali Linux settings through virtual box. My issue is that when I try to click on "choose a virtual optical disk" it's not showing the window that allows me to access where I downloaded my ios file

[image]

Below is the window I'm getting

[image]

But in every tutorial I've watched, this is the window they get.

[image]

This is the tutorial I was trying to follow if it helps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KkJtV4__6w

I hope my question is not too silly, thanks in advance.

Comment: ... did you try clicking the huge button labeled "Add"?

Comment: Or the option "Choose a disk file"?

Answer (score 1):

What you were getting is totally fine and normal.  You should've clicked on "Add" (as in your second screenshot) and eventually you would get the ISO choosing window.

**N.B. Windows, menu and dialog box appearences differ based on platforms. So dont just follow everything in a tutorial blindly.Try to read the options you get.**